# How to retrieve a cell values from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am working on a tracking project in which I am implementing trilateration algorithm. I have data in csv file. I want to retrieve values of cells in csv file one by one in my algorithm. Following is the screenshot of dataset for reference.
[image]

For example: At first (see picture above) I have to retrieve '-49' then '-51' and then '-56' and so on I have to retrieve all the values. Is there any shortcut method through loop to do this efficiently.

Comment: have you checked `csv` module or `pandas` ?

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail? Reading CSV files is a very common question here; please search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas library, you can retrieve columns as below and iterate over them with for loops.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("datasetname.csv")

gateA = data['GateA']
gateB = data['GateB']
gateC = data['GateC']

for i in range(len(gateA)):
    first = gateA[i]
    second = gateB[i]
    third = gateC[i]
```

Comment: Simpler: `for first, second, third in zip(gateA, gateB, gateC):`

Comment: I wasn't sure of that if zipping 3 lists is possible or not, that's why I didn't write that way, but with your answer, I realized that your solution is better.

Comment: Read more about [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)